App doesn't open and go to play sore automatically in my app
I have an offline app.  I run correctly. No problem with APK.
I publish my app in the Play Store with aab file.
When I install it from the Play Store I face some problems. When I open the app automatically goes to the Play Store and says
'you're offline' 'Check your connection or get a notification when you're back online.'
There are internet permissions in my app for ads. I use ads this when user use online.
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

And I also use
I used the same method in another app. That is worked correctly.
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

If you're using ProGuard or R8, make sure you're keeping necessary classes. Add these rules to your proguard-rules.pro file:
-keep class com.google.firebase.** { *; }
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }

